# Gigantic arrays

Tags: php

I'm planning to store gigantic arrays into serialized files and read from them in order to display data within them. The idea is to have a simple, document-oriented, filesystem database. Can anyone tell me if this would be a performance issue? Is it going to be slow or very fast?

Is it worth, filesystem is always really faster?

Comment: More information is needed.  The filesystem is not always (or most of the time even) faster than using an SQL or NoSQL db.  It all depends on your usecase.  So if you can figure out what your exact usage requirements are, you can figure out which is right...

Comment: Define "gigantic"! thousands of entries, tens of thousands, millions, bigger? multidimensional arrays? Serialization/deserialization is slow when working with large arrays, so being able to read a section of an array is probably better.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are some good, fast persistant storage options for key->value data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972362/what-are-some-good-fast-persistant-storage-options-for-key-value-data)

Comment: I'd be more inclined to do a `var_export` (less overhead in loading then `unserialize`).

Comment: What does "gigantic" mean to you?  1 MB, 1 GB, 1 TB?  How many files are you going to have?  Thousands?  Millions?  All the folks telling you to use a real database or a key-value store are probably right, but the details matter when you get to extremes.

Comment: I'm thinking about, MAX, 5,000 entries.

Answer (score 3):

It will be *very* slow. Serializing and unserializing always requires reading and processing the *whole* array, even if you need only a small part.

Thus you are better of with using a database (like MySQL). Or if you need to only access key/value use APC/memcached.

Comment: But that's not how a filesystem database works...  It uses directories and files to organize the data instead of an array or other complex data structure.  So there's no serialization/deserialization needed (well, above what you would need for MySQL/etc anyway)...  I'm not arguing that it's right to implement, but for some use cases (LARGE amounts of sparse data, needing access from shell scripts, etc) it **may** make sense (now, these are few and far between).  But it's by no means "very slow"...

Comment: @ircmaxell: Well the OP talks about serializing large arrays to the filesystem. That certainly doesn't make sense. He doesn't say anything about directories and files.

Comment: whoops.  I must have skipped right over that...  I still think the comment is valid (aside from that one line) otherwise. But I agree, there's no reason to store complex data structures in a serialized file yourself unless you're lazy...

Answer (score 3):

You'll be much better off using a "proper" database - it's what they're designed for. If your data is really in a document-oriented format, consider [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/).

Comment: Unfortunately, i don't want to install anything. I need something that runs just with PHP. Simple and fast.

Comment: The PHP-only solution may be simple. But fast entirely depends on your dataset, operating system, filesystem, and disk architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could implement this without many performance issues, just so long as your arrays don't take forever to (un)serialize and you are able to lookup your files efficiently.  How do you plan on looking up which file to read, btw?

> Is it worth, filesystem is always really faster?

No, this method is not always faster, in fact you'd probably get better performance using some sort of db or cache with what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm using file_put_contents and file_get_contents for writing/reading.

Answer (score 0):

Quite big, a multidimensional array with +- 5,000 entries.